# What makes clang look in subdirectories of the include path?

Tags: c++, clang

Running OS X 10.10.5
When I run the following command: `clang -x c -v -E /dev/null` I see among the output:

---

```
clang -cc1 version 7.0.2 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/local/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents /Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents /Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

---

Now if I look in directory `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include`

I only see one header file there, plus a directory called "c++":

```
ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents /Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  6235 Nov 11  2015 FlexLexer.h
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   102 Nov 11  2015 c++
```

And if look in the directory "c++", then I see directory "v1":

```
ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents /Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  102 root  wheel  3468 Nov 11  2015 v1
```

Finally if I look in directory "v1" then I see the standard c++ library headers such as: string, vector, map, iostream, etc.

Apparently, even though clang tells me it will search in 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/`
It actually looks two subdirectories lower to find the standard c++ headers.

Now if I put a header in `/usr/local/include` the compiler will find that header no problem.

BUT if I create a subdirectory `/usr/local/include/mysub/` and put a header there, the compiler cannot find it.  Now I know, of course I can add a `-I/usr/local/include/mysub` to be able to find headers that I put there.  But my question is this:  *Why the discrepancy??*  Why does clang look two subdirectories below `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/` to find the std c++ headers, but won't look below `/usr/local/include` unless I specifically tell it to do so (with a `-I` flag)??

Is this something that is just hard-coded in clang's source code?  Or is there a way I can configure it to automatically look in subdirectories of any directory in the include path??  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler drivers know where to tell the compiler (or actually the preprocessor) where to look for header files, usually by offsetting from the directory containing the driver executable, and this is hard-coded in the driver. It's generally undesirable to tell the driver  to look in other subdirectories automatically, as this will very often result in very hard to track down bugs. In other words you want to specify the directories explicitly with `-I`.

And if you are developing non-library applications, you should never put anything in /usr/local/include or similar directories. And arguably not even if you are developing libraries.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much, and appreciate understanding the explanation/reasoning behind hard-coding system or standard library header offsets, but forcing the user to use -I for additional headers (for practical/debugging reasons).
However can you explain why I would _not_ put headers for library code that I am developing in /usr/local/include/?   I thought that was the usual place to put locally developed headers that may be used by many applications.  Thanks.

Comment: Apart from anything else, the Unix-like operating systems are inherently multi-user, so if you put something in  one of the system directories there is nothing preventing someone else overwriting it. Those directories are where system header files go, not yours. /usr/local/include is intended to be used for headers for your particular unix-like implementation.

Comment: So where is the best place to put libraries and headers that one wants to make available to the whole system?  Isn't prevention of overwriting best accomplished with file permissions?

Comment: Wherever you like, that you have normal write permissions to. And no, you can't depend on permissions because as a normal user you should not be able to write into /usr/local/include anyway, so you you would need root access, and anyone else with root access can overwrite your files.